# how to select statement in another statement in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to display all orders from my database in desc order according to order_id

im using a while loop to display order_id, order_date, and client info.

---

while using this loop, its is repeating the order_id several times and putting each product in another order display.

for example order # 13 contains 3 products, so order # 13 is repeated 3 times

### this is my code

```
<?php       
include '../php_action/db_connect.php';      
$sql="SELECT * FROM orders left join order_item on orders.order_id=order_item.order_id left join products on products.product_id=order_item.product_id left join category on products.category_id=category.category_id order by orders.order_id desc";
$result=$connect->query($sql); 
while($row=$result->fetch_array())
{  
?>            
<form action="" class="checkout-form" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="place-order">
                <h4>Order number # <?php echo $row['order_id']?> Order Date : <?php echo $row['order_date']?></h4>
                <div class="order-total">
                    <ul class="order-table">
                        <li>Product <span>Total</span></li>
                        <li class="fw-normal"><?php echo $row["product_name"].'  - '.$row['category_name'].'<br>'. $row['product_weight'].'KG ' .' X  ' .number_format($row["product_price"],0).' LBP'?> <span><?php echo 'LBP '.number_format($row['total'],0)?></span></li>
                        <li class="fw-normal">Subtotal <span><?php echo 'LBP '.number_format($row['subtotal'],0)?></span></li>
                        <li class="total-price" style="font-size:1.3em">Total <span><?php echo 'LBP '.number_format($row['grandtotal'],0)?> </span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="payment-check">
                        <div class="pc-item">
                            <label for="pc-check">
                            <?php 
                            echo 'ORDER DATE: '.$row['order_date'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'FIRST NAME: '.$row['client_firstname'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'LAST NAME: '.$row['client_lastname'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'PHONE: '.$row['client_phone'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'CITY: '.$row['client_city'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'ADDRESS: '.$row['client_address'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'BLDG: '.$row['client_bldg'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'FLOOR NO: '.$row['client_floor'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'PAYMENT METHOD: Cash On Delivery';
                            ?>    
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

i want to display the order # and order date, and inside the order table i want to display all products from table order_item where order_item.order_id = order.order_id

how this should work? where is my mistake and how should i fix it?

Comment: Don't `SELECT *`, but rather, select the fields you need (`SELECT orders.order_id, orders.order_date, ...`). This way, you'll avoid having ambiguous column names in your result. Is `$row['order_id']` from `orders.order_id` or `order_item.order_id` ?

Comment: What you want, is a classic [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break). In each loop iteration, you check if the order id is still the same as in the previous one - and then you react accordingly.

Comment: @Cid okay thanks. $row['order_id'] id from table orders. but products are stored in order_item having order_id the same as orders.order_id

Comment: can you please give example on my code? @CBroe

Comment: @youssef are you trying to display all products in an order ? but show order detail once ?

Comment: exactly! I'm tying to display all order details + products in the order without repeating the order which is displaying each product in a separate order (repeating the order but with next product) @OmarAbbas

Comment: okay, I'll post answer to your question.

Comment: @OmarAbbas thank you very much Omar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by many different approaches, here is one very simple approach which you can use to Display the required results.

You can also set the desired format for the values such as `product_price`, and `order_date` etc.

```
<?php       
include '../php_action/db_connect.php';      
$sql="SELECT * FROM orders left join order_item on orders.order_id=order_item.order_id left join products on products.product_id=order_item.product_id left join category on products.category_id=category.category_id order by orders.order_id desc";
$result=$connect->query($sql);

$orders = [];

while($row=$result->fetch_array())
{
    $order_id = $row['order_id'];
    if(!in_array($order_id, array_keys($orders))){
        //Save Order details once  
        $orders[$order_id]['order_id'] = $row['order_id'];
        $orders[$order_id]['total'] = $row['total'];
        $orders[$order_id]['subtotal'] = $row['subtotal'];
        $orders[$order_id]['grandtotal'] = $row['grandtotal'];
        $orders[$order_id]['client_firstname'] = $row['client_firstname'];
        $orders[$order_id]['client_lastname'] = $row['client_lastname'];
        $orders[$order_id]['client_phone'] = $row['client_phone'];
        $orders[$order_id]['client_city'] = $row['client_city'];
        $orders[$order_id]['client_address'] = $row['client_address'];
        $orders[$order_id]['client_bldg'] = $row['client_bldg'];
        $orders[$order_id]['client_floor'] = $row['client_floor'];
    }
    //Push Products into the Order
    $orders[$order_id]['products'][] = [
        'product_name'=> $row['product_name'],
        'category_name'=> $row['category_name'],
        'product_weight' => $row['product_weight'],
        'product_price' => $row['product_price'],
        'total' => $row['total'],
        'qty' => 2,
    ];
}

foreach($orders as $row){
?>            
<form action="" class="checkout-form" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="place-order">
                <h4>Order number # <?php echo $row['order_id']?> Order Date : <?php echo $row['order_date']?></h4>
                <div class="order-total">
                    <ul class="order-table">
                        <!-- Loop through all the products for the current order -->
                        <?php foreach($row['products'] as $product){ ?>
                            <li>Product <span>Total</span></li>
                            <li class="fw-normal"><?php echo $product["product_name"].'  - '.$product['category_name'].'<br>'. $product['product_weight'].'KG ' .' X  ' .number_format($product["product_price"],0).' LBP'?> <span><?php echo 'LBP '.number_format($product['total'],0)?></span></li>
                        <?php } ?>                        
                            <li class="fw-normal">Subtotal <span><?php echo 'LBP '.number_format($row['subtotal'],0)?></span></li>
                            <li class="total-price" style="font-size:1.3em">Total <span><?php echo 'LBP '.number_format($row['grandtotal'],0)?> </span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="payment-check">
                        <div class="pc-item">
                            <label for="pc-check">
                            <?php 
                            echo 'ORDER DATE: '.$row['order_date'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'FIRST NAME: '.$row['client_firstname'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'LAST NAME: '.$row['client_lastname'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'PHONE: '.$row['client_phone'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'CITY: '.$row['client_city'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'ADDRESS: '.$row['client_address'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'BLDG: '.$row['client_bldg'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'FLOOR NO: '.$row['client_floor'];
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo 'PAYMENT METHOD: Cash On Delivery';
                            ?>    
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```